# .xll Add-in isnt work without Visual Studio full version installed

Tags: visual-c++, excel-addins

- UPDATE*

I made a excell addin (.xll file), with some math functions, compiled in c++, and it works normally in my computer. Well, when i try send to other person, isnt work. Excel's show a message like the file is corrupted, and when we try open it, open a sheet with some codes/words/symbols

I've tried to find a solution, but to no avail. But I found out what's the really problem.
After install Visual Studio (full version) in this machine wasn't working, the xll addin works!

So, I think I have a program, feature, component that I installed together with the visual studio (full version) that made the program run. I tried the SDK but was unsuccessful.
Could you help me please? I attached 3 images, one with the addin working and 2 with erros.

PS: i tried compiling version 32 bits and x64, for both excells, and happens in both excels (32 & 64 bits)

[erro 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ho3yo.jpg)

[erro 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AffCV.jpg)

[working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwKJj.jpg)

A colleague ask me to uptdate with the results of -dumpbin /dependents Addin.xll
Follow bellow:

File Type: DLL

Image has the following dependencies:

```
KERNEL32.dll
USER32.dll
MSVCP140D.dll
VCRUNTIME140_1D.dll
VCRUNTIME140D.dll
ucrtbased.dll
```

Summary

```
    1000 .00cfg
    3000 .data
    4000 .idata
    1000 .msvcjmc
    A000 .pdata
   29000 .rdata
    2000 .reloc
    1000 .rsrc
   70000 .text
   32000 .textbss
    1000 .tls
```

Comment: Open a [developer command prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=vs-2019#developer_command_prompt_shortcuts) and run `dumpbin /dependents addin.xll` to see what DLLs your addin requires.

Comment: thank you so much! i will do that!... And... After, can i tell you wich one is it ?

Comment: Once you collect that information you should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63961266/edit) it into the question.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Make sure what you send out to other persons are release builds, not debug ones.

**2)** Users who do not have the VC++ runtimes installed already will need to install the appropriate x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) redistributables from [The latest supported Visual C++ downloads](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads) page (where the bitness depends on which x86 vs. x64 version of the XLL you send them, not on the bitness of their Windows installation).

> ```
> MSVCP140D.dll
> VCRUNTIME140_1D.dll
> VCRUNTIME140D.dll
> ucrtbased.dll
> ```

The `'D'` suffix in those DLL names stands for "Debug". Those are the *debug* C/C++ runtime DLLs, which are used by the Configuration = Debug builds, and are installed as part of the Visual Studio setup. They are to be used during development, but not otherwise deployed, per [Determining Which DLLs to Redistribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/determining-which-dlls-to-redistribute?view=vs-2019):

> Debug versions of applications and the various Visual C++ debug DLLs are not redistributable.